# How can I implement a function in Python that will take in a list of strings and return a new list with all duplicates removed?

Tags: python, jquery, json, list, pytorch

have a list of strings called my_list and I want to create a function called remove_duplicates that will take in this list as an argument and return a new list with all of the duplicates removed.
The order of the elements in the original list should be preserved in the new list.
For example, if my_list is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a'],
then the function should return a new list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].

I have tried to solve this problem by using a for loop to iterate through my_list and adding each element to a new list called result if it is not already in result.
However, this approach does not completely remove all of the duplicates.
I am looking for a way to implement the remove_duplicates function in a way that will correctly remove all duplicates from the list.

dollahzing.blog

Comment: PS my blogpage is dollahzing.blog

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set()` it will remove all the duplicates
example:

```
def remove_dup(list_temp:list)->list:
  return list(set(list_temp))
```